# Combine rows with same position from many different data frames and add column with a calculation result

Tags: dataframe, row, addition, calculated-columns

Let's say I have 36 different data frames, which are all identical (in columns, row length), except for the content.

I am trying to extract two specific rows (401 and 446) of two different columns from each data frame and merge these into a new data frame.

Further, if there is a function, create an additional column that contains the calculation result of the numbers inside the rows of the specific columns, like (446-401 / 446+401).

So far, I´ve tried bind_row to combine the frames, but I can´t figure out an option to select the specific rows, any idea?

```
newdataframe <- as.data.frame(bind_rows(tec1a1p1,tec1a1p2, tec1a1p3, 
                                        tec1a2p1,tec1a2p2, tec1a2p3,
                                        .......))
```

Comment: Hi @fredo, what do you mean 401 and 446? row number 401 and 446 or row with value 401 and 446?  Give us more information would make things easier, thx!

Comment: Hi @WY Hsu, exactly I mean the row number 401 and 406.